# Reverse Array in Access/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

ACCDB file using VBA. I am looking for a specific folder in the path of the database location. It will always be 3 deep from the file, but the depth in the drive is variable. I grabbed the project path, split it, but can't find a function to reverse it. Is there a built-in function or do you have to code it yourself. I have looked around and surprisingly can't find the solution anywhere.

```
    Dim pth As String
    Dim apth As String
    pth = Application.CurrentProject.Path
    apth = Split(pth, "\")
    'Reverse array here
    apth = apth(2) 'Grab second index
    MsgBox (apth) 'confirm folder
    Call search_Project(apth)
```

Comment: Why not just grab the (length-1)th item?  Is there some other reason you need to reverse it?

Comment: That seems like it would work. I am not new to programming, just VBA. Can you (anyone) recommend a good online resource for Access specific VBA. I am used to great online dictionaries for PHP and the like, but I haven't found anything similar for this.

Comment: This may be of some interest [Access 2010 Developer Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841286.aspx). As Tim Williams says, you can `For i=UBound(Array) to 0 Step -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple issues with the code like you can declare a string and then try and use it as an array.  Below is the modified using the length of the array and subtracting 3 to get the position you want.  I also added a check to ensure the length of the array is atleast 3 elements.  Removed the as String for apth as you want to use it as an array.

```
Dim pth As String
Dim apth
pth = Application.CurrentProject.Path
apth = Split(pth, "\")
'Reverse array here
If UBound(apth) >= 3 Then
apth = apth(UBound(apth) - 3)
End If
'Grab second index
MsgBox (apth) 'confirm folder
Call search_Project(apth)
```

Comment: Had to change the "apth = " to a different string, but that works perfect. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
apth = strReverse(Split(strReverse(pth),"\")(2))
```